# How can I update the latest data entry from DynamoDB in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

So I had already searched for solution over the net but haven't found any.
So I want the latest data entry from the dynamoDB table using python and I need to update it. There are several problems I am facing.
**First I am not getting the code to get and update the latest entry in my table. This is the code below I had used for atleast first getting the latest value.**

```
import json
from decimal import Decimal
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

table = dynamodb.Table('Test')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    response = table.update_item(
        Key = {

            "Time": Decimal(4193082887.620961)

        }
    )
    print(response['Item'])
```

**Second, the data in my table is in float format and therefore when I am trying to fetch it, it is giving me error** `DynamoDB does not support float format. Try converting it to decimal`. So I did but now its not matching the value even when the value is present in the DB but in float format.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to have some sort of timestamp column for each item, make that column a sort key of the table and then run `table.query(..., ScanIndexForward=False, limit=1)` which will return items sorted in reverse order and limited to 1 item.
2. Comparing floats is an old problem in boto3 DynamoDB, see the [issue](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/665). Most accepted hack is to do something like this:

```
from decimal import Decimal
dynamo_item = json.dumps(dynamo_response)
parsed_response = json.loads(dynamo_item, parse_float=Decimal)
```

Your mileage may vary, see the issue I linked for other solutions.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try this. Can you tell me if we can only put the primary key in the Key = {} attribute or any key.

Comment: @Jidnyesh I didn't quite get your question, could you please expain?

Comment: I am working on a project where I want to update every data that comes according to a particular expression. For example for every number coming into database, I wanna add one to it. But the data keeps coming every 10 seconds and the lambda function should grab the latest data entry so to update it. I want a python program for it , the DB has an ID parameter already thats already sorted.

Comment: If you want to react to events as they come, you want to set up DynamoDB stream and trigger lambda that way. Then you can take time when you enabled this stream as a starting point and process all the historical data up to that moment.

Comment: Ok ,Thanks a Lot for the help